# Locally linked package devDependencies causing node_modules conflict

Tags: npm

I'm building a package of shared React components.  I use [Microbundle](https://github.com/developit/microbundle) to successfully build in dev dependency.  When I locally link the package to another app the dev dependencies node_modules cause a conflict.

Is there any way to exclude devDependencies when linking a package or exclude everything in peerDependencies from being accessed?

As a workaround I am able to install the package with `npx install-local`, but this step seems unnecessary and seems to imply a larger issue.

Thanks!